# CLP(FD) labeling on possibly infinite domains

Tags: backtracking, prolog

As a follow-up to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37570691/clpfd-and-infinite-countable-domains), I implemented, for my Prolog-based language [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/wiki), my own labeling predicate `brachylog_equals/2` which is not guaranteed to terminate but works for infinite domains:

```
brachylog_equals(Z,Z) :-
    brachylog_equals_('init',10,Z).

brachylog_equals_(I,J,'integer':Z) :-
    fd_inf(Z,'inf'),
    fd_sup(Z,'sup')
    -> (
        (
            I = 'init'
            ;
            I \= 'init',
            abs(Z) #>= I
        ),
        abs(Z) #< J,
        label([Z])
        ;
        I2 is J,
        J2 is J*10,
        brachylog_equals_(I2,J2,'integer':Z)
    )
    ;
    fd_inf(Z,'inf')
    -> (
        (
            I = 'init'
            ;
            I \= 'init',
            Z #=< -I
        ),
        Z #> -J,
        label([Z])
        ;
        I2 is J,
        J2 is J*10,
        brachylog_equals_(I2,J2,'integer':Z)
    )
    ;
    fd_sup(Z,'sup')
    -> (
        (
            I = 'init'
            ;
            I \= 'init',
            Z #>= I
        ),
        Z #< J,
        label([Z])
        ;
        I2 is J,
        J2 is J*10,
        brachylog_equals_(I2,J2,'integer':Z)
    )
    ;
    label([Z]).
```

A few notes about this code:

- This predicate is supposed to be used in automatically generated Prolog code, therefore its name does not describe its function but rather follows a convention.
- `'integer':Z` rather than simply `Z` is simply here to comply with the rest of the project (it is used to check easily the type of arguments in some other predicates)

Here are my worries:

- Is this the most idiomatic solution? (i.e. impose a finite bound on the variable where it has an infinite bound, and increase it recursively if backtracking occurs?)
- Is this actually correct in all cases? (From what I tested it is, but I'm wondering if I missed some odd domains where it would break)
- Is this computationally efficient?

Of course comments on code style (which I know does not respect usual conventions) or code simplication are also welcome.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: The problem is mainly that the CLP(FD) providers are possibly too uninteressted and thus too lazy to provide fair enumeration. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/37952138/502187

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, a very good guidline when coding in Prolog is:

> Everything that *can* be expressed by *pattern matching* **should** be expressed by pattern matching.

By this I mean that it is good practice to distinguish different cases *symbolically* in clause heads instead of using if-then-elses within bodies.

Unfortunately, this guideline is hard to apply in this case because, alas, `fd_inf/2` and `fd_sup/2` use a so-called *defaulty* representation for their arguments. Basically, there are two fundamentally different cases to distinguish:

- infinities (`inf` and `sup`)
- concrete integers.

A **clean** representation would for example be to use:

- `inf` and `sup` for infinities
- `n(N)` to denote the integer `N`

This would help a lot in this example to symbolically distinguish the cases that must be handled, and one day we may have more such predicates. As it stands, we must deal with the *defaulty* representation, which always requires the use of impure constructs (`!/0`, if-then-else etc.) to distinguish the cases.

Nevertheless, we can at least approximate the guideline by putting more decisions into clause heads. This saves a few variables and lets us test the cases more easily in isolation.

Consider for example:

```
unsafe_indomain(X) :-
        fd_inf(X, Inf),
        fd_sup(X, Sup),
        unsafe_indomain_(Inf, Sup, X).

unsafe_indomain_(inf, Sup, X) :- !, % greetings from defaultyness
        infinite_down(Sup, X).
unsafe_indomain_(Low, Sup, X) :-
        unsafe_up_(Sup, Low, X).

infinite_down(sup, X) :- !,  % greetings from defaultyness
        (   X = 0
        ;   positive_integer(N),
            (   X #= N ; X #= -N )
        ).
infinite_down(Up, X ) :-
        (   between(0, Up, X)
        ;   length([_|_], N),
            X #= -N
        ).

unsafe_up_(sup, Low, X) :- !,   % greetings from defaultyness
        (   between(Low, 0, X)
        ;   positive_integer(X)
        ).
unsafe_up_(Up, Low, X) :- between(Low, Up, X).

positive_integer(N) :- length([_|_], N).
```

If `fd_inf/2` and `fd_sup/2` were using a clean representation, *no `!/0` would be necessary* to distinguish the different cases, and we could use the above predicates in more directions! Think about how convenient and elegant this would be. In your own programs, always aim for clean representations, so that you can distinguish different cases by *pattern matching alone*!

Note that I am conciously avoiding the SWI-specific extension of using `infinite` in the second argument of `between/3`, since this feature destroys some important desirable properties of this predicate. You can use patterns like `length(_, N)` to produce arbitrarily large integers on backtracking.

Here are a few example queries:

```
?- unsafe_indomain(X).
X = 0 ;
X = 1 ;
X = -1 ;
X = 2 .

?- X in -1..2, unsafe_indomain(X).
X = -1 ;
X = 0 ;
X = 1 ;
X = 2.

?- X in 5..sup, unsafe_indomain(X).
X = 5 ;
X = 6 ;
X = 7 .

?- X in inf..1, unsafe_indomain(X).
X = 0 ;
X = 1 ;
X = -1 ;
X = -2 ;
X = -3 .
```

I am calling this "unsafe" indomain because there are cases where it may *not* terminate.

---

The more you work with unclean representations, the more you will benefit from **first converting them** to cleaner ones. This keeps the most important predicates of your programs pure and usable in all directions, and the defaulty representations are confined to a small interface layer to interact with users or libraries that use them.

For example:

```
unsafe_indomain(X) :-
        fd_inf(X, Inf0),
        fd_sup(X, Sup0),
        maplist(defaulty_clean, [Inf0,Sup0], [Inf,Sup]),
        unsafe_indomain_(Inf, Sup, X).

defaulty_clean(inf, inf) :- !.
defaulty_clean(sup, sup) :- !.
defaulty_clean(N, n(N)).

unsafe_indomain_(inf, Sup, X) :-
        infinite_down(Sup, X).
unsafe_indomain_(n(Low), Sup, X) :-
        unsafe_up_(Sup, Low, X).

infinite_down(sup, X) :-
        (   X = 0
        ;   positive_integer(N),
            (   X #= N ; X #= -N )
        ).
infinite_down(n(Up), X ) :-
        (   between(0, Up, X)
        ;   length([_|_], N),
            X #= -N
        ).

unsafe_up_(sup, Low, X) :-
        (   between(Low, 0, X)
        ;   positive_integer(X)
        ).
unsafe_up_(n(Up), Low, X) :- between(Low, Up, X).
```

Note how impure constructs like `!/0` are now only needed in the initial conversion step. The rest is quite pure and general.

Answer (score 2):

Before discussing correctness, efficiency and alternative approaches, I first have three smaller suggestions to simplify the predicate a bit:

- Its seems `I2` is nowhere really needed, you can always simply use `J` *instead*.
- for  `J2`, I would stick to CLP(FD) constraints like: `J2 #= J*10`.
- instead of `(\=)/2`, I recommend to use `dif/2`.

These changes make the code a bit easier to read and more uniform, and put us into a better position to discuss the remaining issues.

Comment: As far is I can tell,`I2` **is** `J`, so instead of writing `I2 is J`, you can simply use `J` itself.

Comment: Right nevermind, I'm stupid!